# Finding the Integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R = \{a + b\alpha + c\alpha^2|\ a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}\}\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ where $\alpha $ is a zero of $ x^3 - 4x +2 = 0$

Is $R$ an integral domain?
From my research, I understand that a way to show this is an integral domain is by verifying that it's a subring of C. But am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Usually one uses the definition of an integral domain to show this. Have you tried considering two elements $x,y \in R$ and show that $x\cdot y =0 \Leftrightarrow x =0\ \text{or}\ y=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have basically said how to do it: as *R* is a subset of $\mathbb{C}$ all that is left is to show that *R* is a ring. It contains the unit element 1, so you now need to show that it is closed under addition and multiplication. Addition should be obvious: for multiplication see what happens when you multiply $a+b\alpha+c\alpha^2$ by $d+e\alpha+f\alpha^2$. You can eliminate the  $\alpha^3$ and $\alpha^4$ terms by using the fact that $\alpha^3-4\alpha+2= 0$. Then, as you say, it is a subring of $\mathbb{C}$ so it is a domain.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as you wrote, it is enough to show that $R$ is a subring of $\mathbb{C}$ (since $\mathbb{C}$ is an integral domain).

Note that $0\in R$ so you need to verify that $R$ is closed under addition and multiplication:
For $a+b_1a+c_1a^2,a+b_2a+c_2a^2\in R$,

$\bullet$ $(a+b_1a+c_1a^2)+(a+b_2a+c_2a^2)=a+(b_1+b_2-1)a+(c_1+c_2)a^2\in R$

$\bullet$ $(a+b_1a+c_1a)(a+b_2a+c_2a)= l_4a^4+l_3a^3+l_2a^2+l_1a$ for some $l_i\in\mathbb{Z}$ (that we can compute-but don't really need to). I leave it to you to prove that $l_4x^4+l_3x^3+l_2x^2+l_1x=(x^3-4x+2)f(x)$ for some $f\in\mathbb{Z}$ and that $f(a)\in R$ (why will this imply that the product is an element of $R$?)

Comment: I think the last step is the most crucial step.

Comment: It is, but it is also very standard and not hard at all. I can come back with the (complete) solution if there are more questions..

Comment: Ther is some error I guess, you have taken the general elements to have the same constant terms, this might not be the case and so we will have a biquadratic equation of the form $l_0+l_1 \alpha +l_2 \alpha^2 +l_3 \alpha^3 +l_4 \alpha^4$?